# HtmlAgilityPack example for changing links doesn't work. How do I accomplish this?

Tags: c#, xpath, uri, html-agility-pack

The example on [codeplex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Examples) is this :

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

The first issue is HtmlDocument.**DocumentElement** does not exist!  What does exist is HtmlDocument.**DocumentNode** but even when I use that instead, I'm unable to access the href attribute as described. I get the following error:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'
```

Here's the code I'm trying to compile when I get this error:

```
private static void ChangeUrls(ref HtmlDocument doc)
{
    foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@href"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute attr = link["href"];
        attr.Value = Rewriter(attr.Value);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I Just found that the example was never meant to work...And I've got a solution after reading the example code...I'll post my solution for other people like me to enjoy once completed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my quick solution based on portions of the sample code included in the ZIP.

```
private static void ChangeLinks(ref HtmlDocument doc)
        {
            if (doc == null) return;
            //process all tage with link references
            HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@background or @lowsrc or @src or @href]");
            if (links == null)
                return;

            foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
            {

                if (link.Attributes["background"] != null)
                    link.Attributes["background"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["background"].Value;
                if (link.Attributes["href"] != null)
                    link.Attributes["href"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["href"].Value;(link.Attributes["href"] != null)
                    link.Attributes["lowsrc"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                if (link.Attributes["src"] != null)
                    link.Attributes["src"].Value = _newPath + link.Attributes["src"].Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you could also select the actual attribute nodes: `"//@background|//@lowsrc|//@src|//@href` and modify their `Value` properties directly. You would spare yourself the cascade of `if` statements.