# Getting src attribute from img tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HAP library to parse HTML: http://html-agility-pack.net

I basically just want to retrieve the `src` value from all the `img` tags.

I've tried several thing but I can't seem to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified from the examples page:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm"); //or whatever HTML file you have
HtmlNodeCollection imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
if (imgs == null)
   return;
foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
{
   if (img.Attributes["src"] == null)
      continue;
   HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes["src"];
   //Do something with src.Value
}
```

Comment: @alexn Thanks, I guess that's what I guess when I copy and paste too quickly :)

Comment: i tried this earlier but it didnt work: cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'

Comment: @raklos added an edit which should fix your problem (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517804/htmlagilitypack-example-for-changing-links-doesnt-work-how-do-i-accomplish-thi )

Comment: @raklos Does the newly edited code work for you?  Or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
```