# Parse an Img URL using HtmlNode

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath, nodes

I am trying to grab an img url but I keep getting stuck with the inner or outterhtml which is still kinda a mess. I am grabbing it with

```
HtmlNode htmltable = mydoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//*[@id='mw-content-text']/figure[1]/a/img)");
```

that still leaves me with `<img alt =\"blah\"src=\"http://imageIwant.png\">" string`
is there an easy way to parse out all the extra and just have http://imageIwant.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617696/help-with-getting-src-from-img-tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835868/how-to-get-img-src-or-a-hrefs-using-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlNode has `attributes` namevalue collection which you can cycle through and look for `src` attribute and that will give the url of the image.

`htmltable.Attributes['src']` will give the image url.

Comment: this question has been answered elsewhere

Comment: yup, that was it I am using string htmlurl = htmltable.Attributes[1].Value;

Comment: @RachelGallen, I hope the fact that the question was answered elsewhere wasn't the basis for a downvote.