# parsing links and tables using VB.net HTML AgilityPack

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to do some screen scraping, and discovered the HTML AgilityPack, but am having some trouble figuring out how to use it with VB.net.

The first thing I want to do is find the URL string for an HREF tag if I know the text that is enclosed in the HREF.

The second thing is that I want to do is parse an HTML table, going through each row, and pulling out the data so I can save it to a database (after some basic analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good starting link here on SO: [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

See also this: [HtmlAgilityPack example for changing links doesn't work. How do I accomplish this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517804/htmlagilitypack-example-for-changing-links-doesnt-work-how-do-i-accomplish-this)

And this: [Finding all the A HREF Urls in an HTML document (even in malformed HTML)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2006/10/16/finding-all-the-a-href-urls-in-an-html-document.aspx)

To find a specific HREF, the xpath syntax would be "//a[@href='your url']", meaning: "get any A tag that has an HREF attribute equal to 'your url'.

**EDIT:**

To find an HREF if you only know the text, for example if you have the html text '`<a href="homepage.html">Cars</a>`' and look for homepage.html, then this is how you would do it.

```
        string s = @"<a href=""homepage.html"">Cars</a>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(s);

        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[text()='Cars']");
        Console.WriteLine("href=" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the URL, only the enclosed text. For example, if the HTML is <a href="homepage.html>Cars</a>, I want to be able to search for 'Cars' and get back 'homepage.html'.

Comment: @Avi - I have upated my post.